# Disabled button if status disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I need some help because I can't figure out how to manage a disabled button using functional React.

First of all, **isDisabled** function holds a condition and according on that I set the button state, but I'm not sure where to call the function. The button contains a disabled prop that receives the *disabled* state declared at the beggining.

Below is the code I've tried so far:

```
const MainComponent = ({component}) => {
 const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState('');

const isDisabled = () => {
 if (component.status === 'disabled') {
   setDisabled();
  };
}
 
 return (
  <div>
 <Button> 
 onClick={createItem}
 disabled={disabled}
 Button
 <Button/>
 </div>
 )}
```

Could you provide me some direction and help me on how to keep the button disabled if my component status is disabled?

Thank you.

Comment: you can directly use the result of equality operator for the props value  `<Button> onClick={createItem} disabled={component.status === 'disabled'}Button <Button/>`

Comment: I agree with @anonymous comment and if you still have doubt then you can refer https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-e4265 for implementation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. This would be the most straightforward (but keep reading):

```js
const MainComponent = ({component}) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  return (<div>
  <Button
    onClick={() => {createItem(); setDisabled(true);}}
    disabled={disabled}
  >
    Button
    <Button/>
  </div>);
};
```

However, since `createItem` doesn't appear in your code, I assume that it is a function in the parent scope of your component. If that is the case, then the status should be tracked there and you should get rid of the `useState` in this component. You'd then just use the (reactive) prop to set the button state:

```
const MainComponent = ({component, createItem}) => {
  return (<div>
    <Button
      onClick={createItem}
      disabled={component.status === 'disabled'}
    >
      Button
    <Button/>
  </div>);
};
```